# Dots in function parameter name

Tags: maven, powershell, maven-3, powershell-3.0

Is a parameter name with dots possible in powershell? The obvious approach - see `Dmaven.failsafe.debug` fails:

```
function mvn-failsafe-debug {
  param (
    [string] $Dmaven.failsafe.debug="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,address=Maven,suspend=n",
    [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    $args
  )
  & "$env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat" $args
}
```

Comment: Don't have time to go look now but there was another question about this where I think the discussion ended up with it seeming that the powershell parser was just easily confused about this in some in cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Windows PowerShell Language Specification Version 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389).
The section *2.3.4 Parameters* says

```
parameter-char:
Any Unicode character except
    {   }   (   )   ;   ,   |   &   .   [
    colon
    whitespace
    new-line-character
```

Thus, the dot is not really a valid parameter name character.

Interestingly, it is possible to define a parameter with dots like `${...}`

```
param (
    [string] ${Dmaven.failsafe.debug}
)
```

PowerShell allows the above. But it is difficult to specify such a parameter name on invoking a command.

---

Some experiments:

```
function Test-ParameterWithDots {
    param(
        [string]${Parameter.With.Dots}
    )
    "Parameter : ${Parameter.With.Dots}"
}

# OK
Test-ParameterWithDots value1

# not OK
Test-ParameterWithDots -Parameter.With.Dots value2

# workaround with splatting
$params = @{ 'Parameter.With.Dots' = 'value3' }
Test-ParameterWithDots @params
```

Output:

```
Parameter : value1
Parameter : .With.Dots
Parameter : value3
```

So with spatting we still can specify such a parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

The notation you should be able to use to allow this is with curly braces

```
${Dmaven.failsafe.debug}
```

This is used when the name contains special characters. Typing in [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) is usually to preferred method of defining variables.

Comment: Yes I used that as a workaround `function mvn-failsafe-debug {
  param (
   [string] $Dmaven_failsafe_debug="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,address=Maven,suspend=n"
   , [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
   $remains
  )
  & "$env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat" \`-Dmaven.failsafe.debug=$Dmaven_failsafe_debug $remains
 }`